# Parasitic Passbands in distributed filters

Tags: rf, filter, signal, transmission-line, microwave

it is known that if we realize a filter (for instance a low pass filter) by using distributed elements (transmission lines), there will be some parasitic passbands (which moreover show a behaviour which seems "periodic").

For instance I did this simulation of a Butterworth filter of 5 order: [image][image]

Note that it behaves as a perfect low pass filter only for few GHz after the cut-off frequency. What is the cause of this phenomenon?

Comment: Looks like recursive odd harmonics of filter breakpoint

Comment: Do you know a solution for deleting them?

Comment: You are spanning a whole decade with a 5th order filter that is not a Butterworth nor any other common filter.  There are 2 peaks near 15 GHz and 1 near 25GHz. So this tells me your impedances are wrong on S11:S22 for each delaying line and each line loads the previous ending up with a mess of reflections from mismatched impedances.   Do you need someone to design this for you?  I just explained the cause.  YOu can look at the S21 after each delay and and verify how the load affects it.

Comment: The Q’s for each stage and the group delay both need to be controlled better and much lower Q than what you show,  They usually are centred just before  the breakpoint for a LPF and not scattered across 1 decade of freq.  Try again.  Try  Falstad’s Spectrum filter designer.